# Juniper Network Connect and Windows 8.1 error nc.windows.app.23712

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1

I've been using network connect for years at my company.  I've had Windows 8 since it was released on MSDN.  This morning I connected fine from Windows 8.  I installed 8.1 during lunch and now it continually gives the following error after I log in.

[image]

I have tried running in administrator mode and compatibility mode (windows 7).   I also uninstalled and let the remote portal reinstall.  No dice.

Comment: Your company allows Preview versions of Windows to be installed?

Comment: No, this is my personal laptop.  BYOD.